# how to move the text to the right of the image

Tags: html, css

So, I'm building a site for a college project. The problem is: i use a jsp  that founds every product with a determinated pattern and print them on the webpage but doing so i have 0 control on where to displace infos about price, name and description.

Right now, it displaces img on the left, name of the product at the mid of the img and under the img there is description and then the price. 
I want  the product's name moved on the top at the right of the img and the description under the name. 
What can i do?

```
<section>
  <grid>
    <c:forEach items="${prodotti}" var="prodotto">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <a href="#"><img width="100%" src="https://colourlex.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Peach-stone-black-painted-swatch-12010-opt.jpg"></a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <a class="testoricercaprodotto" href="Prodotto?id=${prodotto.id}">${prodotto.nome}</a>
          <h5>
            <p>${prodotto.descrizione}</p>
          </h5>
          <h6>Prezzo: ${prodotto.prezzo} &euro;</h6>
        </div>



      </div>
       <c:if test="${empty prodotti}">
                <div col="1">Nessun prodotto trovato.</div>
            </c:if>

    </c:forEach>
  </grid>
</section>`
```

[this is what i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldMtF.png)

Comment: Provide a [mcve], which show the _rended_ html. And don't forget the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bootstrap` for that , like in below code i have divided `row` in two parts for `image` and for `description`. Also try to view result in full page . i.e:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
<section>
  <grid>
    <c:forEach items="${prodotti}" var="prodotto">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <a href="#"><img width="100%" src="https://colourlex.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Peach-stone-black-painted-swatch-12010-opt.jpg"></a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <a class="testoricercaprodotto" href="Prodotto?id=${prodotto.id}">edit your post with changes you have made till now ,also screenshot of output you are getting , it would be more easier to help you then .</a>
          <h5>
            <p>edit your post with changes you have made till now ,also screenshot of output you are getting , it would be more easier to help you then .edit your post with changes you have made till now ,also screenshot of output you are getting , it would be more easier to help you then .edit your post with changes you have made till now ,also screenshot of output you are getting , it would be more easier to help you then .edit your post with changes you have made till now ,also screenshot of output you are getting , it would be more easier to help you then .edit your post with changes you have made till now ,also screenshot of output you are getting , it would be more easier to help you then .edit your post with changes you have made till now ,also screenshot of output you are getting , it would be more easier to help you then .edit your post with changes you have made till now ,also screenshot of output you are getting , it would be more easier to help you then .</p>
          </h5>
          <h6>Prezzo: ${prodotto.prezzo} &euro;</h6>
        </div>
       


      </div>
       <c:if test="${empty prodotti}">
                <div class="row">Nessun prodotto trovato.</div>
            </c:if>

    </c:forEach>
  </grid>
</section>

</div>
```

Comment: we're getting closer. Now the product's name goes behind the description and a horizontal scroll-bar has appeared but the positioning is perfect

Comment: edit your post with changes you have made till now ,also screenshot of output you are getting , it would be more easier to help you then .

Comment: now check edited answer , try viewing result in full page . also i have added some dummy data to it ,to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float: left/right` based on where you want to place your image. Also do not forget to add `clear: both;` to the element which is after the division containing your content otherwise you may experience some problems.